# What effects would this magic have?

Tags: science-based, magic, brain

First off, apologies for the lengthy question, and thank-you to anyone who provides some input.

Note that the science based tag is used somewhat loosely.

In this world, magic is not strictly genetic, though that does play a role, as your skill and level of power are defined simply by your mental aptitude.  The more powerful a mind, the greater ease it has in manipulating "potential existence".

Because this magic relies on the mental aptitude of the caster, certain aspects of intelligence play important roles in the abilities of a sorcerer. For instance, the willpower of a sorcerer will impact  their ability to hold their spell in our world. Their ability to concentrate effects the quantity of Vis and Aether they can gather and store around themselves, and for how long they can store it. And their abilities of comprehension, and visualization, effect their ability to create their spell in their mind, and bring it into being.

This also means that the only real restrictions on the *kind* of magic used would be in the psychological and emotional nature of the caster. While a sorcerer may be just as capable of creating fire as lightning, they may prefer the latter. Equally, a sorcerer more capable of gathering Aether than Vis, will have an easier time creating ice or stone, than light.

The "potential existence" I'm referring to here is actually **dark energy**, and **dark matter**, though they go by different names. Through an unknown mechanic, those with powerful enough minds are able to gather and convert Vis (dark energy) and Aether (dark matter) to traditional energy and matter.

Though under most conditions, it will eventually return to its previous state, if a sorcerer has the strength to hold it in "our world" so to speak, it will become whatever they have created permanently. However, magical creations, permanent or otherwise, can be converted back into Vis and Aether by any sorcerer who is capable of replicating the creation. This conversion from more traditional matter and energy, to Aether and Vis, takes the same amount of time to perform in either direction, though how long that is will vary depending on the abilities of the sorcerer performing it.

By holding an object, constructed of Aether, and rich in Vis, in our world, a sorcerer can create an enchanted object. While in their simplest form, these objects serve only as a way for the sorcerer to store a large amount of energy for future use, they can also serve as a delivery device when crafted by a more skilled sorcerer.

As I understand it, this kind of magic could have some interesting effects, especially during the stage of spell casting where Vis and Aether are gathered.
Such effects might include:

- due to the nature of dark energy, and it's tendency to accelerate objects apart, Vis rich spells would create a sort of wind, pushing every thing away from the caster, if enough Vis is gathered, it may even begin to push the caster into the sky.
- If a sorcerer was to attempt the creation of something massive enough, objects would be drawn towards the caster, by the mass of the Aether surrounding them before casting, though this would require a ridiculously monumental spell.
- A crude form of telekinesis could be used, where the sorcerer attempts to position dark energy to push objects around.

  Are my above suppositions correct, and are there other effects this kind of magic may have?

  What would an exceptional, but plausible, individual be capable of?
  How about the average Joe?

**addendum**
Apparently the density of dark energy is even lower than I realised, is it possible to increase its density in my world, without ripping things apart, possibly by increasing the dark matter density proportionally?

Side note, if you have any ideas as to how to exploit this kind of magic, or even the mechanic through which our minds interact with Vis and Aether, I would be interested to read them.

And again, thank-you for any input I receive on this idea.

Comment: A point of clarification here. I'm no physicist, but I was under the impression that "dark energy" is effectively negative gravity, or anti-gravitation. This means that repulsion effects depend on the two masses being repelled. So if you want something to accelerate away at 9.8m/s^2, you need a mass like the Earth's. Doesn't this make this sort of telekinesis insanely powerful? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: While dark energy isn't technically anti-gravity, it does have an anti-gravitational effect, other than that I believe you are correct yes. But even if you gathered enough dark energy to create an acceleration of 0.1 metres a second, you would be able to move objects. I did refer to it as crude, after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you could make matter out of dark matter, you would be very  useful. For one thing, you would  never be hungry, because you could just make food. You would never be unarmed, because you could just create a weapon in your hand.

Making energy would be even more powerful. There are obviously many military applications for making lightning fire or light. But science and technology could be helped by such abilities as well (imagine a steam engine powered by a fire that will never go out, for example).

I'm not sure if your magic users are powerful enough to make large buildings, but even if they can only make small ones, this would completely change the way cities are built.

Combat would change as well. Imagine creating a wall in front of your enemies: there's a cool trick! Military regiments would have to include magic users, at the least to undo the tricks of other magic users working for the enemy.